# Dynamically Convert an Object Using a Type Parameter

Tags: c#, reflection, delegates

Assume you have this:

```
Type theType = typeof(Foobar);
object thingy = new Foobar();
Func<Foobar,bool> FooWork = (f) => return true;
Delegate work = FooWork;

//Without using static cast operations, how do I use 'theType' variable to
//cast the 'work' Delegate back to something I can invoke?
//This next line is very wrong...
bool result = ((Func<theType, bool>)work)(thingy);
```

To restate the comment, how can this be cast without using a static cast operation?  I simply want the `work` variable to hold the `FooWork` delegate without knowing anything about the `Foobar` type.

I can solve my overall problem if I simply make my wrapper class generic, so that the `work` variable becomes generic, but for the present I'm trying to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [`Delegate.DynamicInvoke`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.delegate.dynamicinvoke.aspx):

```
bool result = (bool)work.DynamicInvoke(thingy);
```

---

Other options for resolving these types of problems include the following, each of which provides improved static type safety but may or may not be appropriate for your code.

1. Creating a closure for the parameter. As long as `thingy` is available at the time `work` is defined and won't change, this method will provide better performance than `DynamicInvoke`.

   ```
   Func<bool> work = () => FooWork(thingy);
   ```
2. Making your wrapper generic, and declare `work` using a `Func<T, bool>`, where `T` is the generic type of your wrapper.

Comment: I was afraid I would be consigned to ugly reflection code.  Your solution works.  Absolutely fantastic!

Comment: @BrentArias I edited the answer to provide alternatives as well.